# Latest Ubuntu upgrade caused an error

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to latest version and this caused my system to freeze when booting, after investigation I found that `cupsd` service was not running, if I try to run it manually I get a relocation error.

I do not have the full error message now but it was about a missing symbol in this library file `libidn2.so.0.3.6`.

To solve this I brought this old file `libidn2.so.0.3.3` from my brother's laptop and replaced it with the old file and made sure that the symlink `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0` pointed to the new file.

This solved my issue, I created this question to help you solve this problem if you face it in the near time.

Comment: Please move the last two paragraphs to an newly posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It hosed my system (network, access to terminal etc.) and the update came from

libidn2-0:amd64  2.2.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

which I believe is a backport repository for PHP 7.4.

Here is bug report on backport homepage (scroll halfway down)

https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1247

Link to working deb (18.04 X64)

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

This broke apt and several other services on my servers.

I needed to downgrade as well, but no access to "my brother's laptop." So, I went here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libidn2-0. I then went to the proper architecture download page. I copied to the clipboard one of the links and then used wget to download the library. I installed it with dpkg. It seems to have worked, but apt sees that the library needs to upgraded, but at least apt is working again as well as Samba.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I brought this old file libidn2.so.0.3.3 from my brother's laptop and replaced it with the old file and made sure that the symlink /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 pointed to the new file.

This solved my issue, I created this question to help you solve this problem if you face it in the near time.

Answer (score -1):

the solution at the bottom of this thread works

[Relocation error, error code (127) after last updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173306/relocation-error-error-code-127-after-last-updates)

basically brings you down to 2.0.5