# Relocation error involving libgnutls.so.30, error code (127) after last updates

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates, 18.10, dynamic-linking

After the last update this happened:

```
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
```

What's this? How do I solve it?

The latest command and results obtained:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease [20.8 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [368 kB]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [51.7 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [729 kB]
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [51.7 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [503 kB]
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en [24.3 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [581 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [170 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [263 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted amd64 Packages [6,712 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted Translation-en [2,872 B]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [604 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [979 kB]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [590 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,003 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [201 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [6,788 B]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [7,312 B]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,688 B]
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages [4,152 B]
Fetched 6,424 kB in 4s (1,604 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  landscape-common libidn2-0 libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3.6 libpython3.6-minimal
  libpython3.6-stdlib libsystemd0 libudev1 linux-libc-dev memcached python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal python3.6 python3.6-minimal systemd systemd-sysv udev
23 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 44.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libnss-systemd amd64 237-3ubuntu10.29 [105 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libidn2-0 amd64 2.2.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [66.4 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 237-3ubuntu10.29 [204 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpam-systemd amd64 237-3ubuntu10.29 [108 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 systemd amd64 237-3ubuntu10.29 [2,902 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 237-3ubuntu10.29 [1,101 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 237-3ubuntu10.29 [53.8 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 systemd-sysv amd64 237-3ubuntu10.29 [11.6 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython3.6 amd64 3.6.8-1~18.04.2 [1,414 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3.6 amd64 3.6.8-1~18.04.2 [202 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython3.6-stdlib amd64 3.6.8-1~18.04.2 [1,710 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.8-1~18.04.2 [1,609 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.8-1~18.04.2 [532 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1 [279 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1 [28.3 MB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1 [1,052 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1 [239 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1 [1,915 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1 [1,293 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1 [336 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 landscape-common amd64 18.01-0ubuntu3.4 [85.4 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.15.0-62.69 [1,124 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 memcached amd64 1.5.6-0ubuntu1.2 [109 kB]
Fetched 44.7 MB in 11s (3,952 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 111983 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnss-systemd_237-3ubuntu10.29_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.29) over (237-3ubuntu10.28) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libsystemd0_237-3ubuntu10.29_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.29) over (237-3ubuntu10.28) ...
Setting up libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...
(Reading database ... 111983 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpam-systemd_237-3ubuntu10.29_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.29) over (237-3ubuntu10.28) ...
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_237-3ubuntu10.29_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (237-3ubuntu10.29) over (237-3ubuntu10.28) ...
Preparing to unpack .../udev_237-3ubuntu10.29_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (237-3ubuntu10.29) over (237-3ubuntu10.28) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_237-3ubuntu10.29_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.29) over (237-3ubuntu10.28) ...
Setting up libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...
Setting up systemd (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...
(Reading database ... 111983 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-systemd-sysv_237-3ubuntu10.29_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-sysv (237-3ubuntu10.29) over (237-3ubuntu10.28) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-libpython3.6_3.6.8-1~18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.6:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04.2) over (3.6.8-1~18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-python3.6_3.6.8-1~18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.6 (3.6.8-1~18.04.2) over (3.6.8-1~18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.8-1~18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04.2) over (3.6.8-1~18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-python3.6-minimal_3.6.8-1~18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.6-minimal (3.6.8-1~18.04.2) over (3.6.8-1~18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libpython3.6-minimal_3.6.8-1~18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04.2) over (3.6.8-1~18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-python2.7-dev_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-dev (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) over (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libpython2.7-dev_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-dev:amd64 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) over (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libpython2.7_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) over (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-python2.7_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) over (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) over (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-python2.7-minimal_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-minimal (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) over (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) over (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-libidn2-0_2.2.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libidn2-0:amd64 (2.2.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (2.0.4-1.1build2) ...
Setting up libidn2-0:amd64 (2.2.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
(Reading database ... 112006 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../landscape-common_18.01-0ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking landscape-common (18.01-0ubuntu3.4) over (18.01-0ubuntu3.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-62.69_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-62.69) over (4.15.0-60.67) ...
Preparing to unpack .../memcached_1.5.6-0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking memcached (1.5.6-0ubuntu1.2) over (1.5.6-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...
Setting up landscape-common (18.01-0ubuntu3.4) ...
Setting up memcached (1.5.6-0ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up systemd-sysv (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-62.69) ...
Setting up libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04.2) ...
Setting up udev (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04.2) ...
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...
Setting up python3.6-minimal (3.6.8-1~18.04.2) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-dev:amd64 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) ...
Setting up python2.7-dev (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython3.6:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04.2) ...
Setting up python3.6 (3.6.8-1~18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-60-generic
```

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-62 linux-headers-4.15.0-62-generic linux-image-4.15.0-62-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-62-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-62-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.15.0 | linux-source-4.15.0 linux-tools
Recommended packages:
  thermald
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
```

```
$ sudo apt-get update
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: After last update?  Ubuntu 18.10 reached EOL back 18-July-2019 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/) and is thus off-topic here unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Your paste however refers to bionic?  or 18.04 (18.10 is cosmic) so something is wrong, but 18.10 is off-topic here now due EOL.

Comment: @guiverc I'm experiencing the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04 which is LTS, so this problem does not seem to be exclusive to ubuntu 18.10. However the temporary workaround described in Aaron answer fixed the issue.

Comment: Yeah,latest apt-upgrade downloaded some libidin crap which nuked my boot.Thanks for the question and the answers.

Answer (score 32):

As per Launchpad bug [1843507](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libidn2/+bug/1843507?comments=all), comment [#4](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libidn2/+bug/1843507/comments/4) worked for me, at least temporarily.

```
$ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-mark hold libidn2-0
```

Update: From the bug report, this appears to only affect those using PHP from [launchpad.net/~ondrej](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej)

Update: Ondřej has released an update for his PHP build already. You can downgrade libidn2-0 so that apt will work again:

```
$ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
```

Then:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Have done this and `startx` worked once. Then, after restart, I cannot event get to the terminal. Sic. Time to say hello to Windows again. Such failures are unacceptable.

Comment: @fracz Check comment 12 on the bug report. Might be of use to you.

Comment: I did this and now it seems to work, but I don't have to restart the server? From what I understand is temporary, if I restart, network manager does not start and I remain completely excluded from my server, can you confirm? So what should I do now? Do I have to update in the coming days or not? How will I understand when the problem is solved and will I be able to update and restart the server?

Comment: @alebal Ondřej Surý has released an update to his PPA. You should be able to upgrade right now. You might have to sudo apt-mark unhold libidn2-0

Comment: @fracz You don't keep backup snapshots of your main OS? :( Linux OS is like 10gb. Make backups!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Backups are great, but downtime is downtime.

Comment: @gronostaj And windows never fails? Downtime is unavoidable really. At least with Linux you can disable updates if stability is priority.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I didn't say anything about Windows. I've only pointed out that backups don't solve the problem of broken updates.

Comment: Fair enough, I was responding to fracz I guess. Just feeling defensive :P

Comment: @arron Thanks a lot, I followed the updates and made the upgrades, and everything seems to work, but now my server says: *** System restart required ***, but I'm afraid... I can safely restart or I risk not being able to enter the server?

Comment: @arron All seems to work until today, then today, this: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init(). I think is related to the updates, before work.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron, your "updated" solution (dispensing with the "apt-mark hold libidn2-0" statement) worked for me! I understand that just as your update dispensed with "apt-mark hold", Ondřej [has indicated](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1247#issuecomment-530691103) that pinning with apt-mark hold is no longer desirable now that the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 12):

Download [this libidn2-0_2.0.5-1_amd64.deb package](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.0.5-1_amd64.deb) from the Debian repository to the machine, then run `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/.deb` to install it in place of the faulty Ubuntu package.

Comment: Anyone finding issues on Ubuntu 18.04 should install this package. This works.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Why is downgrading this package a fix?

Comment: @KoenHendriks If you didn't see already, it looks like something went wrong with one of the packages (mentioned above); some context here for the curious: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libidn2/+bug/1843507?comments=all

Comment: Can confirm that this solution also worked on Kali Linux 2018.3.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue on my machine. I was able to connect to the internet via ethernet cable, and pull down the package that [@Mason Pawsey](https://askubuntu.com/users/994734/mason-pawsey) mentioned in their answer.

I wasn't familiar with how to do that, so I found some help from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365091/cant-connect-to-ethernet-after-system-installation-ubuntu-server) by [@chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555).

I was able to downgrade the package, and boot up like normal. However, there was still an entry in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file for `eth0`, and this would stop me from connecting via wifi. So I went into the file, and commented out everything under `auto eth0` (*in case i needed it later*).

After i removed the entry, and restarted my computer, everything was good to go.

I hope this helps whoever comes to this page in the future.